# How to split the first entry of a string that has a letter and number im python?

Tags: python, string

If I have this small python program:

```
str1 = ("S8 10 -945 1689 -950 230 -25 1 1e-13")
print(str1[0,1].split(' '))
```

How would I split the first character from S8 to an individual "S" and "8" instead of just printing"S8"?

Comment: `str1.split()[0]` will give you the string `S8`.  You can then use `list` to get a list of `['S', '8']` -- But the better question is why you're splitting there.  What's the logic that you're trying to code up?

Comment: yep. there are other considerations for a general approach which might not be useful here because you only have published one test case. Are all of your target strings going to have a form of "\w\d ...."? If so, you could code an effective regex.

Comment: It's useful to know if this letter+number will appear more than one time, in any position and in different forms such as "8FF9" and so on...

Comment: This is part of a bigger program where the S in front of 8 executes a evaluation method on the whole line, That's why I need to split the first term.

Comment: Is the first "thing" always exactly two characters? If so, you can just index `str1[0]` and `str[1]` without any splitting at all.

Comment: @dabrams493.................nnn = str1.split(' ')[0] will point to you to the string **S8**. Now you can **yyy = nnn.split('S')**, result is list **['' '8']**...........and yyy[1] is your number after 'S'

Answer (score 0):

You could try appending each character to a list. Then calling int() on each item in the list within a try/except structure. Then use "isint" and if it returns true, insert a space between the int and the character.